# what is a better way to write this code in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to write a better code format than the one i am using that will select three models using a primary id category_id

```
public function show($id)
    {

        $categories = Category::with(
            ['categoryQuestions' => function ($query) {
                $query->inRandomOrder()
                    ->with(
                        ['questionOptions' => function ($query) {
                            $query->inRandomOrder();
                        }]
                    );
                }])->whereHas('categoryQuestions', function ( $query ) use ( $id ){
                    $query->where('category_id', $id);
                })
                ->get();

            return view('client.test', compact('categories'));
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, do you mean better = less code?

Comment: I want to write a better code that this

Comment: You should post this on the code review site

Comment: Use relational Eloquent: Relationships

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how you can write a better code. But you also need to work with you model classes.

First of all, create dependencies using relationships: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)

Secondly, you can use either eager loading or if you always use a certain relationship column for a model, just use $with property on it. As well as create a method that query a relationship with eager loading.

Thirdly, you can use dependency injection and request an instance right away.

```
public function show(CategoryQuestions $id)
```

All you choices depend on your application structure and your decisions as a developer. There are just tools to simplify a development process.

P.S. you can message me privately and share your application code on GitHub, so, I'll be able  to share my opinion about a specific better solition.